# Cycle CLR after Out of Memory Exception?

Tags: memory-management, clr, out-of-memory

Working with very large in-memory files, OutOfMemoryException can occur. When this happens in production, all .NET applications crash, this must be because they all share the same CLR space. Because I cannot understand how to "recycle" the CLR, I end up rebooting the server.

When this happens in VS2010 during debugging, all other .NET things running also fail, but VS2010 itself does not. However, because I cannot understand how to "recycle" the CLR, I end up rebooting on my workstation.

How can I "recycle" the CLR memory space? What about recycling on servers running Win32 Services written for the .NET Framework (non-IIS)?

Thanks.

Comment: Unclear why this was modded down. OOME is a real problem when doing big data operations, and when it happens everything using the CLR (eg all .NET Win32 Services on a server) dies. Knowing how to deal with it in production and development is a real issue.

Answer (score 0):

Cycling the CLR would require exiting and re-running the process.  You can call GC.Collect to force the GC to optimize the memory it's currently using; but as far as it's concerned something needs that memory and can't just "cycle" it.

Comment: What is "the process"? All .NET apps share the same CLR. In services.msc I did not see anything marked as the "CLR process". I also checked Component Services and unlike IIS I saw no clear "CLR environment" I could stop/start.

Comment: @Snowy Share the same CLR?  That's nonsense both in the the fact each process owns it's own memory and must load the CLR independently, as well as nonsense in the fact that you can have more thane one version of the CLR installed an any given .NET app could use a particular version.